# DigitalOcean: Puma service no longer works with systemctl

Tags: systemd

My DigitalOcean environment has mysteriously crashed out of nowhere. Unfortunately, I am unable to bring up my `puma` service, so my Rails application is completely dead in the water.

The command I use to start the service is:

```
systemctl start puma
```

There's a mysterious error that I'm unfamiliar with:

```
Job for puma.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status puma.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

systemctl status puma.service
```

yields:

```
● puma.service - Puma HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/puma.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: resources) since Wed 2018-04-11 17:45:20 EDT; 6min ago
```

`sudo journalctl -xe`:

```
Subject: Unit puma.service has failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

Unit puma.service has failed.

Apr 11 17:56:30 app-master sshd[1124]: Invalid user wp from <some ip>
Apr 11 17:56:30 app-master sshd[1124]: input_userauth_request: invalid user wp [preauth]
Apr 11 17:56:30 app-master sshd[1124]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Apr 11 17:56:30 app-master sshd[1124]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=<some ip>
Apr 11 17:56:32 app-master sshd[1124]: Failed password for invalid user wp from 114.32.120.181 port 39504 ssh2
Apr 11 17:56:33 app-master sshd[1124]: Received disconnect from <some ip> port 39504:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Apr 11 17:56:33 app-master sshd[1124]: Disconnected from <some ip> port 39504 [preauth]
Apr 11 17:56:37 app-master sshd[1126]: Connection closed by <some ip> port 49964 [preauth]
Apr 11 17:56:41 app-master sshd[1128]: Did not receive identification string from 103.89.91.78
Apr 11 17:56:48 app-master sshd[1129]: fatal: Unable to negotiate with 103.89.91.78 port 51781: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Apr 11 17:56:49 app-master sshd[1131]: Did not receive identification string from 103.89.91.78
Apr 11 17:56:50 app-master sshd[1132]: fatal: Unable to negotiate with 103.89.91.78 port 55251: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Apr 11 17:56:53 app-master sshd[1134]: fatal: Unable to negotiate with 103.89.91.78 port 60600: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Apr 11 17:56:54 app-master sshd[1136]: Did not receive identification string from 103.89.91.78
Apr 11 17:57:06 app-master sshd[1137]: Invalid user wp from <some ip>
Apr 11 17:57:06 app-master sshd[1137]: input_userauth_request: invalid user wp [preauth]
Apr 11 17:57:06 app-master sshd[1137]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Apr 11 17:57:06 app-master sshd[1137]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=<some ip>
Apr 11 17:57:08 app-master sshd[1137]: Failed password for invalid user wp from 114.32.120.181 port 41202 ssh2
Apr 11 17:57:08 app-master sshd[1137]: Received disconnect from <some ip>port 41202:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Apr 11 17:57:08 app-master sshd[1137]: Disconnected from <some ip> port 41202 [preauth]
Apr 11 17:57:10 app-master sshd[1139]: Connection closed by <some ip> port 34578 [preauth]
Apr 11 17:57:15 app-master sshd[1141]: Did not receive identification string from 103.89.91.78
Apr 11 17:57:42 app-master sshd[1142]: Invalid user wp from <some ip>
Apr 11 17:57:42 app-master sshd[1142]: input_userauth_request: invalid user wp [preauth]
Apr 11 17:57:42 app-master sshd[1142]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Apr 11 17:57:42 app-master sshd[1142]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=<some ip>
Apr 11 17:57:44 app-master sshd[1142]: Failed password for invalid user wp from 114.32.120.181 port 42864 ssh2
Apr 11 17:57:44 app-master sshd[1142]: Received disconnect from <some ip> port 42864:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Apr 11 17:57:44 app-master sshd[1142]: Disconnected from <some ip> port 42864 [preauth]
Apr 11 17:58:11 app-master sshd[1144]: Did not receive identification string from <some ip>
Apr 11 17:58:17 app-master sudo[1147]:   <hidden> : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/<hidden> ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
Apr 11 17:58:17 app-master sudo[1147]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by <hidden>(uid=0)
```

I have zero idea what the problem is here. I have never seen `wp` user in my life, so I don't even know what that is. I can't understand why suddenly I can't run puma on my DigitalOcean droplet any more.

Comment: You really should be reading, and showing people, the log of your HTTP server rather than the log of your SSH server.

Comment: The most useful logging may be in `journalctl -u puma`

Answer (score 1):

Chances are the resource you've run out of is either memory-related or CPU related.

Your DigitalOcean accounts includes CPU and Memory monitoring for your Droplet on the dashboard. You should check it. Before the crash, was the Droplet maxing out the memory our CPU?

You can also check all the resource limits related to systemd that apply to Puma:

```
 systemctl show puma
```

Cross-reference that output with the [documentation for the systemd resource control directives](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html).

Finally, search for all mentions of puma in the journal:

```
 journalctl -x | grep puma
```

You may find some clue there as to which resource as exhausted.